# Algebraic factors of $5^n+6^n+10^n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I run currently a factoring project on $$f(n)=5^n+6^n+10^n$$ This expression has only no small prime factor , if $6\mid n$ holds. A prime occurs for $n=3168$ (not a proven prime, but extremely probably a prime) and no other $n\le 50\ 000$. I search a prime factor for the cases $$n=1038,1188,1230,1470,1842,2022,2778,3030,3090,3294,3318$$ Note that the current year is in the wanted-list. My question now is

> Are there forced factors (algebraic/aurifeullian or similar kinds of factors) for some $n$ ?

This would explain why this expression is prime so rarely.

Comment: A comment, maybe worthwhile, is that $5^n+10^n$ can be factorised into $5^n(1+2^n)$ and that $2^n+1$ is divisible by 3 for odd $n$ and notice that $6^n$ is also divisible by $3$. Thus for odd $n$ is $f(n)$ divisible by $3$.

Comment: I get $11 \mid f(n)$ if $n \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$ and $23 \mid f(n)$ if $n \equiv 2 \pmod{22}$. There are most likely more of these; I don't know if they would match your rarity observations.

Comment: And it is true that $7|5^n+6^n+10^n$ for $n$ a power of $2$.

Comment: When $n\equiv\pm1\pmod3$ the sum is divisible by $7$

Comment: $\large 5^{2022}+6^{2022}+10^{2022}$ factor found [P37](http://www.factordb.com/index.php?query=5%5E2022%2B6%5E2022%2B10%5E2022).

Comment: @Piquito Can you maybe explain why that is true?

Comment: Least common multiplier of 5, 6 and 10 is 30. we consider prime 31. we have:$5^{30}+6^{30}+10^{30}\equiv 3\bmod 31=30m+m+3$. We know there are infinitely many primes of the form $p=30 k+r$, where $r=1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29$. So we must have $r=m+3=7, 11, 13, ...$ or $m=4, 8, 10, 14, . . .$ if there if a prime factor of that form.

Comment: That is if n is a multiple of 30 it iss probable to get a primes of the for $30k +r$.

Comment: @René Bruin: Look at my answer and try to get yourself a proof for $n\equiv-1\pmod3$ following a similar way.

Comment: Ah of course, could have known it myself!

Comment: The question is not about very small prime factors for which we can of course easily find necessary conditions for $n$ to rule them out but whether $5^n+6^n+10^n$ can be proven composite for some $n$ for which there is no small factor like we can show that $n^2-1$ cannot be prime for large $n$ because of $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$

Comment: [semiprime](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000003851813610)

Comment: P32 factor found for $n=1038$

Comment: Which prime factor did you find?

Comment: [partial factorization](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000003845049455)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof for prime $7$ when $n\equiv\pm1\pmod3$

►First for $n\equiv1\pmod3$

$f(n)=5^{3n+1}+6^{3n+1}+10^{3n+1}$.

$f(n)\equiv(-2)^{3n+1}+(-1)^{3n+1}+(-4)^{3n+1}\pmod7$

By induction, it is true for $n=0$. Let it be true for $n$ so for $n+1$ we have $$f(n+1)\equiv(-2)^3(-2)^{3n+1}+(-1)^3(-1)^{3n+1}+(-4)^3(-4)^{3n+1}\pmod7$$
Thus $$f(n+1)\equiv-f(n)\equiv0\pmod7$$

Similarly $f(n)\equiv0\pmod7$ when $n\equiv-1\pmod3$